# Is Cantor's diagonal argument necessary when we already know that real numbers are infinitely different in two dimensions?

Tags: combinatorics, logic

To make sense of how the diagonal method applied to real numbers show their uncountability while not when applied to rational numbers, you need the concept of real numbers being infinitely unique in two dimensions while rational numbers are only infinitely unique in one dimension, which shows that any "new" number created is same as a rational number already in the list. But doesn't that concept/definition itself already assume that having 1 dimension of infinite does not correspond to having 2 dimensions of infinite? Why is the diagonal method proof even needed?

Comment: What do you mean by "dimension of infinite"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all, in what sense are the rationals one dimensional while the real numbers are two dimensional? Second, dimension - at least in the usual sense - is unrelated to cardinality: $\mathbb{R}$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ have the *same* cardinality, for example.

The answer to the question of why we need the diagonal argument is that vague intuitions about cardinalities **are often wrong**. Often when we have an "obvious" idea about cardinality it's either fundamentally imprecise (e.g. you can't formalize what "dimension" means here) or it turns out to be wrong (e.g. after a formal definition of "dimension" is given, it turns out that larger dimension does not imply larger cardinality).

(In particular, **geometry tends to yield terrible intuition for set theory**. Geometric intuition for example can also be taken as indicating that the rationals and the reals must have the *same* cardinality since the former is dense in the latter and so "fills up the same space" in some sense.)

Comment: Thanks. Let me try again to make more sense with my low mathematical maturity. It appears that to appreciate diagonal argument creating a unique real number not already enumerated requires you to already have a sense of real numbers having a different level of "cardinality" than rational numbers. How? You need to realize that rational numbers have a finite way to represent them (integers and repeating decimals)... which is different than real numbers who have infinte ways ("after the decimal") which I was just calling the second "dimension"). >>> continued...

Comment: @csp2018 In principle, though, what's to rule out some really clever way of finding "finitary" representations for real numbers? Once we appropriately formalize that, Cantor's argument is exactly what *proves* that there cannot be such a representation method (not just that we haven't thought of one yet).

Comment: And this notion to me already feels intuitive and convincing, and is required to see how the diagonal method is even relevant in the first place. Doing the diagonal method seems like a round about way to say the same thing and doesn't seem to add any extra convincing.

Comment: @Noah_Schweber perhaps I'm missing something fundamental, but how does the diagonal argument prove that other representations can't exist, instead of the other way around, where the diagonal argument depend on these definitions to make sense in the first place?

Comment: @csp2018 "this notion to me already feels intuitive and convincing" That doesn't matter - can you make it *precise* and then, having done so, can you *prove* it? "is required to see how the diagonal method is even relevant in the first place" I'm not sure what that means. "Doing the diagonal method seems like a round about way to say the same thing and doesn't seem to add any extra convincing." What it adds is **an actual proof of a precise statement** - as opposed to just an intuitive claim (which plenty of people initially disagree with!).

Comment: " the diagonal argument depend on these definitions to make sense in the first place" What step in the diagonal argument do you think depends on assumptions of non-finite-representability of the reals? **Try writing out your argument completely and precisely**; that's the only way you're really going to see why, at some step along the way, you're smuggling in the thing we're trying to prove. (Incidentally, it will be easier to work with infinite binary strings instead of reals, just because then we don't have to care about integer parts or non-unique decimal representations.)

Comment: Alternatively, it may help to consider sets of reals which are countable yet are more complicated than $\mathbb{Q}$ - for example, the *algebraic real numbers*. These don't have eventually repeating decimal expansions in general, but they're still countable, the point being that they *do* have a more complicated kind of finite representation. The issue is that just saying "any decimal expansion corresponds to a real number" doesn't immediately rule out the possibility that somehow we can nonetheless find a really weird way of representing real numbers in a finite way - that's what Cantor does.

Comment: Okay, thanks for helping me. I've already worked out how the diagonal method shows there are real numbers that can't be enumerated by natural numbers. But can it show that rational numbers CAN be enumerated by natural numbers?

Comment: @csp2018 No, you need a different argument to do that - basically, you just need to actually exhibit such a counting. It's not hard to do, though, so I've never heard it given a name.

Comment: Ah... I think that is where I was confused. Like you said, I made too many assumptions about what the text I was studying was claiming. Thakns!